# URL with Cyrillic words doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have these 2 links

```
<a href="my_path/РУБАШКИ.php">РУБАШКИ</a>  // DOESN'T WORK
<a href="my_path/newfile.php">try</a>      // WORKS
```

I'm sure that the path to the files is correct, I think the problem is due to the Cyrillic.

Why this happens and how do I fix this?

Comment: This special characters in URLs are scary ... do you control the encoding of your pages ?

Comment: Fix it not using cyrillic on file names.

Comment: @Aimcorz dont mind them, it is very much possible to use non-latin characters in a URL. the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I know it's possible. But the point about the *file* may be valid, though

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it "doesnt work"? do you receive an error in the browser's developer console?

Comment: @Banana  I get error 404, page not found

Comment: Check if the address bar shows correct url after redirection. Another thing you can try, is copy&paste the page name into the link. The cyrilic characters look the same, but they might be different.

Comment: i have a feeling that your `"my_path/"` is incorrect. make sure you are using the `../`,`./` and `~/` correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode the URL, for example using `urlencode("my_path/РУБАШКИ.php");`. That should take care of the client side. If it still doesn't work, you need to change some server settings. It could be that your filesystem encoding doesn't match your webserver's encoding or that some security plugin disallows unicode characters. To provide more specific instructions, I'd need to know your exact environment.

Just fyi: The comments above are definitely right by saying that you should't use cryllic names in files. It just provokes errors.

Answer (score 0):

What if you'll try it encoded:

```
<a href="my_path/%D0%A0%D0%A3%D0%91%D0%90%D0%A8%D0%9A%D0%98.php">РУБАШКИ</a>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried it before your answer but I got the same error: 404